# Why do we care about permutation on first $n$ positive integers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

A permutation on $n$ symbols of a set $S$ is a defined as a bijection from $S$ onto (or into? I'm not sure which is the correct one to use) itself.

So, why do we only keep on using $S = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}= [1,n]$ as the set in permutation group? Why not go with a general $n$ sized set?

One reason I can think of is perhaps because we could always define a bijection from $[1,n]$ onto the set. Cool but why is that helpful, if at all? And then how is working with general $n$ sized sets not useful?

For instance, I can't see why $(a \ b \ c )$ as cycle would be more difficult to read than $(1 \ 2 \ 3)$?

Comment: Because $S_{|A|}$ and $S_A$ are equivalent, dude!

Comment: Why would you write a permutation as mapping $S_{a_i}$ to $S_{a_{\sigma(i)}}$ when the labels could just be $a_i=i$, so $S_i$ maps to $S_{\sigma(i)}$?

Comment: @J.G. One problem I have with defining a bijection from $[1,n]$ to the set is that maybe I'm also defining an order on the set? I guess ordering of the elements may somehow be relevant in permutations, no?

Comment: In short: Because small integers are short. It is much easier to work with (1 2 3) than ("Mr. Bean", "Dr. Jekyll", "Mr. Hyde"), because it is shorter. And if you are interested in permutations of those three nice guys, you can easily number them first. But yes, sometimes we *do* write permutations of other objects in full, if that feels convenient.

Comment: " One problem I have with defining a bijection from [1,n][1,n] to the set is that maybe I'm also defining an order on the set?" Indeed, permutations are the bijections that do this. It sounds like your concern is that $S_i\mapsto S_{\sigma(i)}$ could just as easily be represented as $S_{\pi(i)}\mapsto S_{\sigma(\pi(i))}$, so why should we use $\pi=\operatorname{id}$? I guess because it's "natural".

Comment: Defining an order: If you find that a problem, it won't help to use alphabetic names. They have an order too. If you do not think that order is relevant, just don't use it.

Comment: @William You will implicitly define an order on the set only if you think of $[1,n]$ as an ordered set. You don't have to, so there is no problem. Actually it is not more than labeling the objects in a set. Then working with the objects does not essentially differ from working with the labels.

Comment: It isn’t technically more useful to use $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}.$ But $S_n$ should be defined as the set of permutations on a particular set. Given two sets of the same size, the are isomorphic groups, but there are $n!$ different ways to construct that isomorphism, and none is primary. So it becomes problematic to use different sets if we want to talk about one group. So we pick the most obvious.

Comment: We do define other groups in terms of permutations on sets. For example, the dihedral groups are isomorphisms of cycle graphs, and thus are represented as permutations on the nodes of a graph.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Makes sense. Could it also be because we may have permutation on infinite sets? Is $S_∞$, a permutation on $\mathbb{N}$, a thing?

Comment: Why is the question, downvoted? Please provide reason so I can improve it. Don't just downvote from the shadows and run away. :(

Comment: Permutations on infinite sets are a thing, even on uncountable sets (an in that case integers are no longer that useful as labels, because you don't have enough of them).

Comment: @drhab I get it, I need to think of bijections as "re-labeller" and nothing more.

Comment: I find it somewhat difficult to believe that the answer to this has any *mathematical* content, where I don't count readability, running out of letters etc. Working with $[1,n]$ being useful doesn't make working with a general set $S$ non-useful : it just means that notation is reduced, we can be concrete where needed. Finally : as a *teaching* tool in school, people may permute groups of horses and politicians to help kids understand symmetries, but at the abstract level of those who study group theory, they can easily switch between notions. At the end of all this, $[1,n]$ is just the...

Comment: ... easiest to understand, and as Thomas mentions, there's no reason to change $[1,n]$ to anything unless that *anything* has structure that allows for interesting mathematical interpretations (such as the vertices of a regular polygon along for a permutation to be interpreted as a "reflection" or a "rotation", for example).

Answer (score -2):

> For instance, I can't see why $(a \ b \ c )$ as cycle would be more
> difficult to read than $(1 \ 2 \ 3)$?

Simple: because the cycle could be $(31\  33\  34)$.

Comment: Forgive me but what?

Comment: @William If the size of your set $S$ is bigger than $26$, you will run out of letters to denote the elements of the set. If the set contains elements $a,b,c$, you literally cannot write out all the elements if there are $27$ elements. You will never run out of numbers.

Comment: My point was that why only numbers (or even letters). What's wrong with (Cayley  Hamilton Hitler) as cycle? Cayley maps to Hamilton and so on. But my entire discrete math textbook only ever uses $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ to build it's theory. Why is that? How it more useful?

Comment: Who says there is anything *wrong* with Cayley Hamilton and Hitler? You can work with them, but mathematically you gain nothing because the structure of possible permutations is still exactly the same as with 1, 2 and 3. You are just using longer names.

Comment: 5xum, there are more letters than digits; the OP could rewrite $(31\ 33\ 34)$ as $(ca\ cc\ cd)$.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Okay I think I get the point. I need to think of bijections as "re-labeller".

Comment: @BarryCipra But everyone knows what comes after "$9$". Not everyone knows what comes after $z$. For example, if you ask in my country, the answer would be $ž$, the last letter of the alphabet.

Comment: @5xum, excellent point. But I think what the OP is asking is why it's so important that the objects being permuted have any natural order at all.